# Create a new user without root password

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have to create a database in a Windows Server 2008 remote machine, which already had MySql Server 5.5 and MySql Workbench 5.2 installed. Since I wasn't granted the password to the *root* user, I tried to create a new user.

In MySql Workbench I tried to open the *Manage Security* option, to no avail, since it asked for the password.

In the command prompt I tried to run `mysql` but it returned the following error message.

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Is there any way to create a new user without having prior access to the *root* user?
More generally, is there any workaround to create and use a database without access to *root*?

Comment: The whole idea of a root user is to prevent random people from making new accounts. Is it really a good idea to let someone with no credentials create users and databases?

Comment: @tadman That makes perfect sense. I was asking out of curiosity, since I'm not too familiar with these systems. It seems I'll have to ask for acess to root.

Comment: It is possible to reset the root password if you don't know it, or you can just trash all the databases and bring up MySQL from scratch if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to be the root user, but you must have rights to create a user. You can get those rights with the `grant create user` statement. Apparently, you don't have those privileges, so if you need them, you should ask your administrator.

So the answer is: There is no workaround. You don't have to be root, but you must have certain privileges.

In practice, if you need an extra user, the administrator is more likely to create one for you than to give you the rights to create them yourself. But that's something he and you need to figure out yourselves. :)